# How to display multiselected images in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am making an app for iPhone and want to give users the ability to multiselect images from their photo-library. I already have a working code for user to select four images at a time.

But I can't select 1 or 2 or 3 images at a time. I want to select the 1 or 2 or 3 images at a time.

This is my code. I have struggled for 3 days without finding a solution. Please help me anybody.

Thanks in advance.............

```
-(void)choosePhotoFromExistingImages
{   
    ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initImagePicker];   
    elcPicker.maximumImagesCount = 4;   
    elcPicker.returnsOriginalImage = NO; //Only return the fullScreenImage, not the fullResolutionImage 
    elcPicker.imagePickerDelegate = self; 
    [self presentViewController:elcPicker animated:YES completion:nil];   
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{    
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
}

- (void)displayPickerForGroup:(ALAssetsGroup *)group
{   
    ELCAssetTablePicker *tablePicker = [[ELCAssetTablePicker alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];   
    tablePicker.singleSelection = YES;  
    tablePicker.immediateReturn = YES;    
    ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tablePicker];   
    elcPicker.maximumImagesCount = 0;   
    elcPicker.imagePickerDelegate = self;   
    elcPicker.returnsOriginalImage = NO; //Only return the fullScreenImage, not the fullResolutionImage 
    tablePicker.parent = elcPicker;

    // Move me   
    tablePicker.assetGroup = group;
    [tablePicker.assetGroup setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allAssets]];
    [self presentViewController:elcPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{   
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
    {   
        return YES;
    } 
    else 
    {   
        return toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
    }
}

#pragma mark ELCImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods

- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info
{    
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];    
    CGRect workingFrame = _scrollView.frame;    
    workingFrame.origin.x = 0;   
    NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[info count]];   
    for (NSDictionary *dict in info) 
    {     
        UIImage *image = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];      
        [images addObject:image];     
        UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]; 
        [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];     
        imageview.frame = workingFrame;        
        [self.view addSubview:imageview ];        
        self.chosenImages = images;
    }    
    UIImageView *image1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 240, 40, 40)];    
    image1.image=[images objectAtIndex:0];   
    [self.view addSubview:image1];
    UIImageView *image2=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 240, 40, 40)];   
    image2.image=[images objectAtIndex:1];    
    [self.view addSubview:image2];
    UIImageView *image3=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 240, 40, 40)];    
    image3.image=[images objectAtIndex:2];    
    [self.view addSubview:image3];    
    UIImageView *image4=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 240, 40, 40)];   
    image4.image=[images objectAtIndex:3];   
    [self.view addSubview:image4];  
}

- (void)elcImagePickerControllerDidCancel:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker
{   
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Did you try Demo from [ELCImagePickerController repo](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController)? It runs for me OK and allows to select as many as you want under *maximumImagesCount*.

Comment: @AntonGaenko thanks for your response.I am also using ELCImagePickerController.If i click 4 images it will display.But if i click 2 or 3 or 1 images it will not display.I willl get exception.If i select 2 images i will get exception like this "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]".Please help me i am struck nearly 2 days.

Comment: have you tried setting maximumImagesCount to something lower?

Comment: ya i tried it.It is working.But my requirement is maximum 4 images selection.But my main problem is I can't select 1 or 2 or 3 images at a time. I want to select the 1 or 2 or 3 images at a time...Thanks for your response

Comment: See my answer. You need to rewrite getting images code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link for the [Tutorial](https://github.com/chiunam/CTAssetsPickerController). Its works fine in my project.Try this

Hope its useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check your code in `- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info`

For example, you create array with length of 2, but in code below you try to get `image3.image=[images objectAtIndex:2];` and `image4.image=[images objectAtIndex:3];`. It's not a surprise that your code throws exception.

Good luck!